# Why Debugger unable to reach breakpoint on override method

Tags: java, debugging, spring-ldap

I tried running this code but unable to call method **mapFromAttributes()** and debugger only reach class **PersonAttributesMapper** line but unable to debug and call override method.Few days ago it was running smoothly.
Using tomcat 9 and jdk 8

```
  @Service 
  public class PersonRepository{

    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

    public List<Person> getPersonNames() {

        LdapQuery query = query()
                    .searchScope(SearchScope.SUBTREE)
                    .countLimit(10)
                    .attributes("cn")
                    .base(LdapUtils.emptyLdapName())
                    .where("objectclass").is("people")
                    .and("uid").isPresent();

           return ldapTemplate.search(query, new PersonAttributesMapper());

        }
        private class PersonAttributesMapper implements AttributesMapper<Person> {  //debugger reaches here

           @Override
           public Person mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {  // unable to reach here
                Person person = new Person();
                person.setName((String)attrs.get("cn").get());
                return person;
            }
        } }
```